# Golang + Avconv error (exit status 254)

Tags: go, libavcodec

I'm getting "panic: exit status 254" on the second line.

Can you spot the mistake I made here:

```
command := exec.Command("avprobe", "inputfile.mp4 -loglevel quiet -show_streams -frame_size -print_format -show_format -of json")

output, err := command.StdoutPipe();
if err != nil {
    log.Panic(err)
}

if err := command.Run(); err != nil {
    log.Panic(err)
}

json.NewDecoder(output).Decode(&struct1)
```

Comment: If any of the answers solved your problem you should mark that answer as accepted (button below the votes of that answer). This then marks the question as resolved. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Package exec
>
> [`func Command`](http://golang.org/pkg/os/exec/#Command)
>
> ```
> func Command(name string, arg ...string) *Cmd
> ```

For example,

```
arg := []string{
    "inputfile.mp4",
    "-loglevel", "quiet",
    "-show_streams",
    "-frame_size",
    "-print_format",
    "-show_format",
    "-of", "json",
}
command := exec.Command("avprobe", arg...)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are running the equivalent of

```
avprobe "inputfile.mp4 -loglevel quiet -show_streams -frame_size -print_format -show_format -of json"
```

I am guessing avprobe doesn't like that, try

```
command := exec.Command("avprobe", "inputfile.mp4", "-loglevel", ...)
```

You can also use `exec.CombinedOutput()` to get the output from avprobe and see what it says.

Comment: Thanks! The CombinedOUtput helped. I ended up using command.Output as opposed to the standard output.